# Controls do not change color or text, when I call method from another form

Tags: c#, winforms, mdi

**Note: Form2 is MDI Child Form and I set all Form1's modifiers to Public**

my method is not working when i want to change color or text or etc...
For example: There is two forms, Form1 and Form2. In Form2: label1.Click event i did this:

In Form2:

```
private void label1_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        Form1 f1 = new Form1();
        Label name = ((Label)sender);
        f1.getInfoLabel(name);
    }
```

Okay, everythings working until here, but in there:

In Form1:

```
public void getInfoLabel(Label obj)
    {
        pictureBox1.BackColor = obj.Forecolor; //not working
        TextBox1.Text = obj.Text; //not working
        MessageBox.Show(obj.Forecolor.ToString()); //working
        MessageBox.Show(obj.Text); //working
    }
```

Any help? Please.

Comment: You're creating a *new* instance of `Form1`. Did you instead intend to interact with an *existing* instance of `Form1`? If so, you need to arrange for that to happen via other means. E.g. if `Form2` was created by `Form1`, perhaps you need to make `Form1` `Form2`'s parent, or to pass it across explicitly in a constructor parameter or property.

Comment: are you by any chance creating two (or more) copies of Form1 instead of acting on the one which is already there? `Form f1 = new Form()` will create a new (probably invisible) instance of Form1. If this form is already open on your screen, you need to execute your code against a reference to that form, not create a new copy of it

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever im working on MDIParent and Form2 is child form into Form1 like Visual Studio Designer. I think its from MDI. Maybe?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of

```
Form1 f1 = new Form1();
```

use

```
Form1 f1 = this.MDIParent as Form1;
if (f1 != null)
{
    f1.getinfolabel(sender as Label);
}
```

As has been pointed out, you are creating a new Form1 instance and interacting with that instead of interacting with the parent form. As long as you are correctly setting MDIParent of Form2 then the above should work.

An alternate is to use:

```
Form1 f1 = Appliction.OpenForms.OfType<Form1>().FirstOrDefault();
if (f1 != null)
{
    f1.getinfolabel(sender as Label);
}
```